# Necessity of encoding for certain models of computation

Tags: computability, computation-models, turing-completeness

Consider the following model of computation (from [here](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/models/08-universal.pdf)).
[image: FRACTRAN]

Although Fractran is Turing-complete, it assumes that the "user" is able to perform the steps of encoding the input ($2^{n + 1}$) and decoding the output ($\log_3(x) - 1$). That is, as mentioned by the second bullet, there are computable functions that cannot be computed by Fractran without an external encoder/decoder.

Is there any theory about this topic? I want to be able to characterize whether a computational model is "actually" Turing-complete, in that it can "natively" represent every computable function on the natural numbers, or if it presupposes the existence of an external encoder and decoder.

I would appreciate any terminology or references, since I'm not even sure what to Google in this case.

Comment: [Magic The Gathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering) is a Turing complete *game*. Also [Baba is You](https://hempuli.com/baba/) is another Turing complete game. I'm interested whether you think they "natively" represent every computable function or not. In my opinion - they do. In fact, I don't think there is even a non "native" way to represent computable functions - since this topic is purely subjective. Some might even consider turing machines as not "native" enough!

Comment: I think another way to view the question I'm asking is: are there any theoretical implications of the statement in the second bullet point? Maybe the correct question is, are there models of computation that are bijective?

Comment: Good question, but probably hard to answer. For Fractran the encoding can be considered native as its datastructure consists of a single number. A sequence of natural numbers $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ is encoded using powers of prime numbers $2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}$. Retrieving the second number sounds more natural than taking a logarithm. I think I recall some discussions in the past about natural encodings, when Wolfram's [rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) was shown to be Turing complete. The proof is very clever, but the input needed to be embedded into an infinitely repeating string.